# CSS rules not applied if filename is taken from user

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to HTML/javascript program that takes in a filename, parses the file and displays its contents in a table. The issue I am facing is that the if I take the filename as a user input via HTML forms, my CSS rules are not applied to the table I create via javascript to display the parsed contents. But if I hard code the filename and then call the javascript function then the CSS rules do get applied. Not sure where I am going wrong.

Note : I have gone through other similar question but none of then answer this specific situation.

At the end I have given a sample XML data too. One can assume that XML tag names and structure will not vary for different files.

Below is the html, javascript and css code

HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="loadxml.js" async></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="userPrompt">
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="filename"/><br><br>
            <button onclick="callDOMHandler()">Submit Query</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callDOMHandler(){
        //var filename = "xmlFileName.xml";
        var file = document.getElementById("filename").value;
        loadXMLDoc(file);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript code

```
function is_all_ws( nod ){
  // Use ECMA-262 Edition 3 String and RegExp features
  return !(/[^\t\n\r ]/.test(nod.textContent));
}

function is_ignorable( nod ){
   return ( nod.nodeType == 8) || // A comment node
     ( (nod.nodeType == 3) && is_all_ws(nod) ); // a text node, all ws
}

function loadXMLDoc(filename){
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.write("<table>");
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Row");

for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    if(i==0)
        document.write("<tr class=\"topRow\">");
    else
        document.write("<tr>");

    var totalRows = x[i].childNodes.length;
    for(j=0;j<totalRows;j++){
        if(is_ignorable(x[i].childNodes[j])){
            /*do nothing*/
        }
        else{
            document.write("<td>");

            if(j==(totalRows-2)&&(i!=0))
                document.write("<img id=\"logo\" src=\""+x[i].childNodes[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"\"/>");
            else
                document.write(x[i].childNodes[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                document.write("</td>");
        }
    }
    document.write("</tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");
}
```

CSS file

```
table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;}
th, td {padding: 5px;}
.topRow{text-align: center; font-weight: bold;}
#logo{width: 100px; height: 100px;}
```

Sample XML

```
<Workbook>
<Worksheet>
    <Table>
        <Row>
            <Data>Symbol</Data>
            <Data>Name</Data>
            <Data>HomePage</Data>
            <Data>Logo</Data>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Symbol>ABC</Symbol>
            <Name>AbcBcdDef</Name>
            <HomePage>http://www.homepage.com/</HomePage>
            <Logo>http://imageURL.png</Logo>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Symbol>XYZ</Symbol>
            <Name>XyxYxzZxy</Name>
            <HomePage>http://www.homepageURL.com/</HomePage>
            <Logo>http://image.png</Logo>
        </Row>
    </Table>
</Worksheet>
```

Comment: Can you create an element with document.write? I've always used document.createElement. Isn't document.write for writing strings?

Comment: I am new to this. But document.write works fine for me. At least in the terms that it allows me to render the content. I used friebug to inspect the html page and it shows all the elements with the id's i am writing.
But I will try with createElement and check if the code works then. Thanks

Comment: The code lacks the part that actually fetches the file. A sample XML file is missing (and so is the description of the structure of XML files used).

Comment: Other parts of code are missing too (function is_ignorable), and the XML structure assumed is non-obvious, and the button submits the form, which is hardly meant here. Please provide actual code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Andreas to answer your question, `document.write` can do anything. Don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has several issues. Lack of root element end tag in XML data is probably just a copy and paste error. Using `button` inside a `form` causes confusion, since after invoking the `onclick` handler, the form gets submitted, causing a reload of the page; this can be prevented using `type="button"` in the `button` tag. But the main problems are that you are modifying the document with `document.write()` and using a synchronous request; about the latter, the Chrome console shows the following warning: “Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.”

The code behaves differently in different situations. It is difficult, and probably futile, to analyze this in detail. The reason why the style sheet is not used is that `document.write()`, when executed in an event handler, starts a new document, and the newly created document lacks the `link` element. I cannot tell why you have observed something different when the filename is given as a constant (I did not).

A minimal fix is to add the `type` attribute and to make the JavaScript function construct the `table` markup as a string (instead of using `document.write()`) and return it as the value. Then you can make its caller simply replace the document body content with an element parsed from that value.

The HTML file would then be:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="loadxml.js" async></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="userPrompt">
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="filename"/><br><br>

            <button type="button" onclick="callDOMHandler()">Submit Query</butto\
n>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callDOMHandler(){
//      var file = "xmlFileName.xml";
        var file = document.getElementById("filename").value;
        document.body.innerHTML =
          loadXMLDoc(file);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And function `loadXMLDoc` in the JS file would be:

```
function loadXMLDoc(filename){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",filename,false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

    var table = "<table>";

    var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Row");

    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        if(i==0)
            table += "<tr class=\"topRow\">";
        else
            table += "<tr>";

        var totalRows = x[i].childNodes.length;
        for(j=0;j<totalRows;j++){
            if(is_ignorable(x[i].childNodes[j])){
                /*do nothing*/
            }
            else{
                table += "<td>";

                if(j==(totalRows-2)&&(i!=0))
                    table += "<img id=\"logo\" src=\""+x[i].childNodes[j].childN\
odes[0].nodeValue+"\"/>";
                else
                    table += x[i].childNodes[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                table += "</td>";
            }
        }
        table += "</tr>";
    }
    table += "</table>";
    return table;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works and solves my issue for now. But there is one question, what if the XML data is very large (say a XML file > 1 GB). Will a string hold that much data ?

Comment: @Jay, that would be a new question. But if you expect to be able to deal with the data in the DOM, I don't see why it would not work as a string (which tends to consume less storage).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there was no real need to change the other bits of app just to take a name from a text input - you could have just assigned the contents of the input to the same variable as the hard coded string and then pass it on as before. You could also get the contents from loadXMLDoc into a variable and debug the output to see that you're getting the same contents both times.

```
/*var filename = "xmlFileName.xml";*/
var filename = document.getElementById("filename").value.trim();

var bodyString = loadXMLDoc(filename).toString();
document.body.innerHTML = bodyString;
```

Since you you have the same variable in and out in both cases and you can debug them to check that they have the same string contents both times.